# How can I structure this code to avoid repetition?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, structure

I have two conditions, `a` and `b`. One block of code should execute if `a` is true, then another if either `a` or `b` is true. Is there a better way to structure the code than the following - can I avoid the repeated test of `a`?

```
if a or b:
    if a:
        <block 1>
    <block 2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without the repeated test. To verify this, just write down the truth table.

However you could avoid the nesting of  your `if` statements:

```
if a:
    <block 1>
if a or b:
    <block 2>
```

This could make the code more readable.

I assume here that `a` is a boolean value and not a placeholder for a more complex expression that might be expensive to evaluate. In the latter case you would of course evaluate the expression only once and assign the result to a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks. `a` is a placeholder for a more complex expression - I will follow your advice and create a variable to hold the result.